# Query matching value of a dictionary in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, dictionary

I have a document with a field called "vpns" whose values are a dictionary:

```
"123": "abc",
"456": "def",
"789": "ghi"
```

I'm aware of searching for a particular item in an *Array*, but not by a *value* in a dictionary.

I'd like to get ALL documents that have **"def"** in their *values of vpns*.

Thanks!

Comment: Which mongo server version are you on ? Possible via $objectToArray in 3.6 but not a performant solution. Can you change to array of embedded documents structure ? Something like `vpns:[{k:"123", "v":"abc"}, {k:"456", "v":"def"}...]}` and you can use regular find.